# Line between boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

Is there a way to insert a line which connect some points over the boxplot?
For example, show a boxplot and a line that connect every median value or a line that connect some other points.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you insert or link to a graphic that shows approximately what you want? It could be made in something other than matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly plot in the same axes as your boxplots resides in.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(20)
b = np.r_[a, np.random.rand(20)*1.6]
c = np.random.rand(20)*2.1
data = [a,b,c]
mins = [d.min() for d in data]
maxes = [d.max() for d in data]

plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(data)
# simply plot the data as usual
plt.plot([1,2,3], mins, c="r", lw=2)
plt.plot([1,2,3], maxes, c="g", lw=2)


plt.show()
```